# How can I save IBM Quantum API token to local environment?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have an IBM Quantum account. How can I save the IBM Quantum API token to local environment so that I can access services including real quantum systems, simulators and Qiskit Runtime programs on my local machine using Qiskit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an IBM Quantum account or log in to your existing account by visiting
   the [IBM Quantum login page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/login).
2. Copy (and/or optionally regenerate) your API token from your
   [IBM Quantum account page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account).
3. Take your token from step 2, here called `MY_API_TOKEN`, and run:

   ```
   from qiskit import IBMQ
   IBMQ.save_account('MY_API_TOKEN')
   ```

   The command above stores your credentials locally in a configuration file called `qiskitrc`.
   By default, this file is located in `$HOME/.qiskit`, where `$HOME` is your home directory. If
   you are still using `Qconfig.py`, please delete that file and run the command above.

See more info here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider#setting-up-the-ibm-quantum-provider

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [Keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) package for [storing and retrieving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831213/1176573) the secrets on local OS. It leverages the OS provided security and supports mac, windows and linux. This avoids token leak into plain text and notebooks.

If you are on windows os, you can store the credentials into [windows credential manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0) and retrieve it using the `keyring`.

###### Storing token: (One time)

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("IBMQ", "ibmq-token", "the-token-goes-here")
```

###### Retrieve token:

```
retrieved_token = keyring.get_password("IBMQ", "ibmq-token")
```

Then perform login:

```
IBMQ.enable_account(retrieved_token)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the package `qiskit.providers.ibmq` is being deprecated. The latest way to load it is via using `service`.

Authenticate to the service by calling QiskitRuntimeService with your IBM Cloud API key

```python
# do pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime first
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
 
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum", token="<MY_IBM_QUANTUM_TOKEN>")
```

or, optionally use the `save_account()` method to save your credentials for easy access later on, before initializing the service.

```python
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
 
# Save an IBM Quantum account and set it as your default account.
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel="ibm_quantum", token="<MY_IBM_QUANTUM_TOKEN>", overwrite=True)
 
# Load saved credentials
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
```

and now you can also test it:

```python
 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
 from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Sampler
 
 # Create empty circuit
 example_circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
 example_circuit.measure_all()
 
 # You'll need to specify the credentials when initializing QiskitRuntimeService, if they were not previously saved.
 service = QiskitRuntimeService()
 backend = service.backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")
 job = Sampler(backend).run(example_circuit)
 print(f"job id: {job.job_id()}")
 result = job.result()
 print(result)
```

or you can check which backends you have access to:

```python
service.backends()
```

** Updated from the recent comments.

Answer (score 1):

from @yet-another-random-guy,

i think the syntax changed from `set_as_default = True` to `overwrite= True`

->

```
 from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
 
# Save an IBM Quantum account and set it as your default account.
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel="ibm_quantum", token="<MY_IBM_QUANTUM_TOKEN>", overwrite= True)
 
# Load saved credentials
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
```

This works for me, thanks @yet-another-random-guy for your timely update!