# IBMProvider.load_account() AttributeError: type object 'IBMProvider' has no attribute 'load_account'

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying to resolve the below deprecation warnings I am getting while using IBMQ framework.

```
DeprecationWarning: The qiskit.IBMQ entrypoint and the qiskit-ibmq-provider package (accessible from 'qiskit.providers.ibmq`) are deprecated and will be removed 
in a future release. Instead you should use the qiskit-ibm-provider package which is accessible from 'qiskit_ibm_provider'. You can install it with 'pip install qiskit_ibm_provider'. Just replace 'qiskit.IBMQ' with 'qiskit_ibm_provider.
IBMProvider'
```

My earlier code was:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.save_account('key', overwrite=True)
IBMQ.load_account()
```

Now, I have changed it below:

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
IBMProvider.save_account('key', overwrite=True)
IBMProvider.load_account()
```

But now I am getting the error:

```
 IBMProvider.load_account()
AttributeError: type object 'IBMProvider' has no attribute 'load_account'.
```

It would be great if I can be helped on this.

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23639/how-can-i-save-ibm-quantum-api-token-to-local-environment/35456#35456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation<sup>[[1](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit-ibm-provider/qiskit_ibm_provider.IBMProvider)]</sup>:

> Once credentials are saved you can simply instantiate the provider like below to load the saved account and default project:

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
provider = IBMProvider()
```

So, there is no need to call `load_account()`

Comment: Thank you @Egretta.Thula